# escaping completion handler that is never called: memory leaks?

Tags: swift

If I pass a completion handler to a function and the completion handler never gets called, will I be creating a memory leak?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on what the function does, and what the completion handler does. If the completion handler cleans up shared resources, for example, then that cleanup will not occur if the completion handler is not called, and that could easily lead to leaks. For this reason, you should always endeavor to make sure that your completion handlers are always called in writing asynchronous functions and methods.

Comment: I don't think it would ever be a good design idea to rely on completion handler clearing some resources. On the other hand, it wouldn't be a good idea to create a function execution path that never calls the completion handler neither.

Comment: Often times there's no choice; if you need to create some temporary resources, use some asynchronous API, and get rid of those resources when you're done, there's not much choice other than to use the completion handler. If you have other work that needs to be done after an async API completes, again, it's the completion handler.

Basically, it should be considered part of the contract when using an async API that the completion handler will eventually be called, and if it doesn't, it's a bug. When Swift gets async/await, things will be much better, since it will be possible to enforce this.

Comment: Well I think we just misunderstood each other. Obviously if there's an option to provide a completion handler you are allowed to expect that it will be eventually called.

Comment: In my case there are no resources to be cleaned up. It is just something I noticed. A function which only calls the completion handler if a certain condition is met (within a specific block) and ignores it otherwise,. Just poor design. I will make adjustments.  Thanks.